# DirectCasted Objects in Structures get Cloned?

Tags: vb.net, pointers

I use a structure for wich can hold a data-variable as an object :

```
Structure parse_object
    Friend data As Object
End Structure
```

in this data-variable i want to save different types of structures
for example this one:

```
Structure drive_data
    Friend num_steps As UInteger
End Structure
```

I initialize it like this :

```
Dim driveConf_comm as parse_object
Private Sub init()
    driveConf_comm = new parse_object()
    structure drive_data
    Dim d As New drive_data()
    d.num_steps = 0
    driveConf_comm.data = d
End Sub
```

Now i want to change the value 'num_steps' in a callback

```
Private Sub cb(ByRef num_steps as UInteger)
    Dim d As drive_data = DirectCast(driveConf_comm.data, drive_data)
    d.num_steps = 100000
End Sub
```

But this doesn't change the variable, write d back to driveConf_comm.data :

```
    DirectCast(driveConf_comm.data, drive_data).num_steps => 0
    driveConf_comm.data = d
    DirectCast(driveConf_comm.data, drive_data).num_steps => 100000
```

Has DirectCast cloned my struct?

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but DirectCast is not to blame.  That's just the way value types (aka structures) work.

Every time you assign a value type to another variable or field or property, you make a copy of the values in the structure.  As you noticed, this means that modifications to the copy do not affect the original.

Comment: @Oli No, but if you turn it into a class instead of structure, you will get reference type semantics, which is similar.